# Swift and iOS this class is not key value coding for the key numbers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I tried build project and i have this error.

**`2017-08-24 15:25:53.942 calculator[6278:756282] Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<calculator.ViewController 0x7fba6b509360> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key numbers.'`**

I have only this in ViewController...

```
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func numbers(_ sender: UIButton) {
        label.text = label.text! + String(sender.tag-1)
    }
```

Comment: Open your storyboard & check for all linking.You will get Yello color mark on unsatisfied linking.

Comment: Check you `@IBAction` of `numbers` in your storyboard

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-v?rq=1 – most probably a missing connection

Comment: Och thank you boys i got it